# Не могу составить код для текста

Tags: python, текст

В русскому языке, как правило, после букв Ж,Ч,Ш,Щ пишется И,А,У, а не Ы,Я,Ю. Проверить Заданный текст на соблюдение этого правила и исправить ошибки ( с учетом исключений: ПАРАШЮТ, БРОШЮРА, ЖЮРИ).
Была идея просто запустить счетчик в тексте, но что-то не срослось. Потом я хотел решить через 'ord', но тоже ни черта не вышло. После хотел написать функцию, которая будет через цикл for выискивать ошибки, да вот не знаю как написать. Текст любой может быть. Можно просто где-то найти да вставить в переменную и не париться)

Comment: Да используйте регулярку-то...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

почему бы не применить алгоритм:

1. найти буквы Ж, Ч, Ш, Щ
2. посмотреть буквы после них и если они входят в множество "Ы Я Ю" и не являются словом-исключением - выдать ошибки или исправления

если в лоб:

```
word = "шыпчики"

is_error = False

for letter in ['ж', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ']:
    for index in range(len(word)):
        if word[index] == letter and index < len(word) - 1 and word[index + 1] in ['ы', 'ю', 'я']:
            is_error = True

print("Ошибка" if is_error else "Норма")
```

можно зайти с регулярного входа:

```
import re

word = "шыпчики"

result = re.findall(r'[жчшщ][ыюя]', word)

print("Ошибка" if len(result) else "Норма")
```

это и покороче и поудобнее

Comment: Автору надо не только найти, но и исправить. PS. Правильно - "шшыпчики".

Comment: @Akina, ну главное найти, а исправить можно заменой - можно ввести словарь соответствий и на основании словаря менять

Comment: Я немного не понял, как работает условие в "print". Впервые вижу, чтобы "if" так записывали. Можно пожалуйста объяснить?

Comment: @Игорь Смирнов, как и в других языках, типа C/C++ и т.д. (`if (условие) ? правда : ложь`) в питоне есть тернарный оператор - `правда if условие else ложь`

Comment: Понял, спасибо!